# Update MySQL values onclick button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to change a button and the status on mysql when I click onclick button.
When status is "Active" then it should be update in database as "Inactive" and update the button colour.
If status is "Inactive" when user click then it should be update in database as "Active" and button colour
The php to update the value on mysql seems ok (updateStatus.php) but have problems to know how to do the js code.

The two buttons possible:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_status">Active</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_status">Inactive</button>
```

**updateStatus.php**

```
include("db_connection.php");
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $register_status = $_POST['register_status'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `register_status` = '$register_status'  WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
$('body').click('#btn_status', function(event){
        //alert("button is clicked");
        var nid = $("#nid").val();

        $.post("ajax/updateStatus.php", {
                nid: nid,
                register_status: register_status
        }, function (data, status) {
                alert("button is clicked");
        });

});
```

anybody help to update this code?

Comment: I'm not going to hassle you on how this is a mysql security risk (prepare for that). However, my question for you what isn't working?

Comment: I need to know how can execute the js and how can change the button status. I need to update to the opposite state once a click is executed

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear

HTML

```
<button data-status="active" class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
<button data-status="inactive" class="btn btn-warning">Inactive</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document)
 .on('click', '[data-status]', function(a){
  a.preventDefault();
  var button = $(this);
      if(button.data('status') == 'active'){ //active
          //change button color e.g button.css('background-color', 'red');
      }else if(button.data('status') == 'inactive'){ //inactive
          //change button color e.g button.css('background-color', 'blue');
      }
});
```